# Can I use range() in the map() function?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was just testing out the map() function to get to know it and I ran into a problem. I was just trying to multiply all the numbers in `numbers` between zero and two by three:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4]

test = map(lambda x: x * 3 for x in range(3), numbers)

print test
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, what is it? Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use lambdas with `map()` - use list comprehensions instead! It's more readable and you avoid the function call overhead

Comment: K I'll keep that in mind. I actually saw lambda being used this way in another question on here asking whether to use list comps or map(). Which lead me to this dilemma :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map()` does the comprehension for you - No need to add another (in fact you can't, as you've already seen).

The correct syntax is:

```
map(lambda x: x * 3, numbers)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
[x * 3 for x in numbers]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I use  the `range()` function to to only multiply certain numbers by 3?

Comment: @Amon That isn't what the range() function is for

Comment: @Amon Oh, I think you want to check if the number is *in* `range(3)`. You can do `[x * 3 for x in numbers if x in range(3)]`

Comment: I see, should I not use map() at all then?

Comment: @Amon I only use `map` for things like turning all items in a list from a string to an integer (eg `map(int, mylist)`) and not really for stuff like this. You should probably use a list comprehension, and keep ThiefMaster's advice in mind :)

Comment: @Amon If you want to use map, you can use a combination of `map` and `filter`, like this:
`map(lambda x: x*3, filter(lambda x: 0<=x<=3, numbers))`. This form is equivalent to the comprehension listed by Haidro.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
test = map(lambda x:x*3, numbers)
```

The thing is, map takes two arguments - the function to be mapped, and an iterable that the function will be mapped over.  In this case, your lambda is your function, and `numbers` is your iterable.  Note that in Python, you'd generally do `[x*3 for x in numbers]` for a list or `(x*3 for x in numbers)` for a generator (lazy eval)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two distinct ways of doing this:

**Using a list comprehension**

```
[x*3 for x in range(3)]
```

**Using map and a lambda expression**

```
map(lambda x:x*3, range(3))
```